# Where should I include .dll files from bin folder in libraries?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

To use C++ libraries we need to copy `.dll` files from bin folder, we are either instructed to paste them in the `project directory` OR in `C:/windows32/`.

Does it matter where we paste `.dll` files besides the scope of accessibility ?

Comment: Don’t muck around with the files in `%SYSTEMROOT%`, and especially don’t overwrite existing system files, if you have an alternative.

Comment: @Davislor yeah but why? I want to know whats happening behind your advise and please write it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

It’s a very bad idea to write files to the system directory if you have an alternative.  (And if you did need to, you’d check the environment variables instead of hardcoding.)

At best, no other program will install a library by the same name, so you’ll have a bit of extra junk in your system directory.  It can’t be removed when you uninstall the program, because it was never registered and you have no way of knowing if some other application needs it.

At worst, two different programs will install different versions of `FOO.DLL` and one of them will break.  This is affectionately known as “DLL Hell,” and the solution was for everyone to put their DLLs in the project directory.  (Or sometimes, the vendor’s Common Files.)

Comment: If the DLLs are a standard (for example official driectX dlls) then would it be ok to put them OR expect them in system root? and then design our application such that if it needs a modified version of same DLL or a DLL with similar name then application looks for it's own resource directory first.

Comment: In that case, you would run the redistributable DirectX installer as part of your installation process.  It’s programmed to detect if a newer version is already installed.  **Definitely** do not overwrite the files already in the system directory with ones that might be older.